# Conditional FROM clause

Tags: sql-server

My coworkers are using entity framework and have got 3 (schematically) identical databases. These databases are updated and modified by their application. I am writing another, separate application to gather information about their application.

I am trying to use stored procedures but having trouble. It seems I must have three copies of my query in every stored procedure (one for each database) and `JOIN` them all at the end. I don't want to have three copies of every query with only the table name changed. Can I specify using a parameter, CASE statement, or something else the table I use in my FROM Clause?

Comment: If there are 3 databases, why not just maintain 3 different connection strings in your application configuration and switch if you want to test on a different database?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I'm working with stored procedures. However, your suggestion is a good one and I will consider moving the SQL to my application.

Comment: no need to move your sql code you can still call stored procedures stored in your dbms from code; sorry i just assumed an application behind that but as you commented you already have one, how are you calling your stored procedure until now?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I edited my question. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Check my answer once. you can't use case statement but you can pass the table name as parameter and use a IF condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with stored procedures, you can pass the table name from which you want to query as parameter like

```
create procedure sp_test
@tab_name varchar(10)
as
begin
if(@tab_name = 'Table1')
select * from Table1
else if (@tab_name = 'Table2')
select * from Table2
else
select * from Table3
end
```

Then run your SP like

```
exec sp_test 'Table1'
```

**EDIT:**

As per your comment you want to change the DB name in your query. So in `DB.HistoryOne JOIN DB.HistoryTwo` you want to change the `DB` to `DB1`. You can do it like below in a procedure

```
    create procedure sp_DB_change
    @DBname varchar(10)
    as
    begin      
   declare @sql varchar(200);
set @sql = 'SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(s, StartDate, OtherStartDate)) AS time1 ,
CAST(OtherStartDate AS Date) AS [Date] 
FROM DB.HistoryOne 
JOIN DB.HistoryTwo ON HistoryOne.Id = HistoryTwo.Id 
WHERE StartDate IS NOT NULL 
AND OtherStartDate IS NOT NULL 
AND OtherStartDate > DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY CAST(OtherStartDate AS DATE)';

select @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'DB',@newdb)
exec (@sql)
end
```

Then run your SP like

```
exec sp_DB_change 'testDB'
```

So your original query

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(s, StartDate, OtherStartDate)) AS time1 ,
CAST(OtherStartDate AS Date) AS [Date] 
FROM DB.HistoryOne 
JOIN DB.HistoryTwo ON HistoryOne.Id = HistoryTwo.Id 
WHERE StartDate IS NOT NULL 
AND OtherStartDate IS NOT NULL 
AND OtherStartDate > DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY CAST(OtherStartDate AS DATE)
```

Will be converted to

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(s, StartDate, OtherStartDate)) AS time1 ,
CAST(OtherStartDate AS Date) AS [Date] 
FROM testDB.HistoryOne 
JOIN testDB.HistoryTwo ON HistoryOne.Id = HistoryTwo.Id 
WHERE StartDate IS NOT NULL 
AND OtherStartDate IS NOT NULL 
AND OtherStartDate > DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY CAST(OtherStartDate AS DATE)
```

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing now. The problem is that my query is large and I would like to avoid having three copies of it in between if statements in the same stored procedure.

Comment: @sirdank, that can be avoided using dynamic SQL. post me your query and can help you further.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Here is the part of my query that I am copying and pasting three times for each database
`SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(s, StartDate, OtherStartDate)) AS time1
    ,CAST(OtherStartDate AS Date) AS [Date]
 FROM HistoryOne JOIN HistoryTwo ON HistoryOne.Id = HistoryTwo.Id
 WHERE StartDate IS NOT NULL
 AND OtherStartDate IS NOT NULL
 AND OtherStartDate > DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE())
 GROUP BY CAST(OtherStartDate AS DATE)`

It's not extremely long but I am faced with this problem frequently I feel like so I'd like the knowledge.

Comment: @sirdank, your query contains 2 tables `HistoryOne and Historytwo` which one should be the variable one?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the DB name from the query. In reality, it is `DB.HistoryOne JOIN DB.HistoryTwo`. `DB` is what I need to change.

Comment: @sirdank, see edited answer. let me know if this is what you are trying to achieve or my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Two options: dynamic SQL, or a UNION ALL statement.

```
SELECT columnlist
FROM TABLE1
WHERE @param = 'Table1'
UNION ALL
SELECT columnlist
FROM TABLE2
WHERE @param = 'Table2'
UNION ALL
SELECT columnlist
FROM TABLE3
WHERE @param = 'Table3'
```